# SilverStripe 3: Can a module extend mysite/code/Page.php?

Tags: module, extend, silverstripe

Good afternoon,

I don't know if what I want to do is possible, so here goes.
I have a module that extends Page_Controller, but I want certain functions to be accessible via the site root.
Eg: getMyDataObjectList(); 
Currently, they only work if I go through the normal MVC routing structure.

I've found that when I place the function 'getMyDataObjectList' within '/mysite/code/Page.php' it works.
The problem is, I don't want to place the code in there. I want it bundled with my Custom Module, but to work the same as though it was in 'mysite/code/Page.php'

[Example Scenario]
**site root:** *http://[somesite].com*

By default, the '*Page.ss*' template loads.
I would like the theme developer to be able to call my module functions (API) within any template/Layout page, and have the result returned from the **site root**
Currently, this only works if I move the "API" functions to '/mysite/code/Page.php'
If the code is in my module, then data is only returned when you go to:
*http://[somesite].com/[module_controller]*

Can this be achieved? If so, how?
Thanks for your assistance.

**[Update - Code Solution]**

```
///>MyExtension.php
class MyExtension extends Extension{
    public function getMyDataObjectList(){
         return 'object list goes here!';
    }
}//class

///>[Module] => _config.php
Object::add_extension('Page_Controller', 'MyExtension');
```

And as always, I do a (/dev/build?flush=1) just in case.
Thanks to: 'simon_w'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is relatively straightforward. Simply, create an `Extension` subclass with your methods in them and then add that to `Page_Controller`. An `Extension` subclass is almost exactly the same as a `DataExtension`, they're just for classes other than DataObjects.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. I've edited the post above to show the code solution for anyone who may want to see the code.

Comment: @add better to post the solution as an answer

Comment: Okay, noted. Thanks.